# How to style two images so their combined width is a fixed number, and their height is the same

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a website where I display two images side-by-side. I want to style them so that, regardless of their dimensions:

1. Their combined width is a set size (500px, for example)
2. Their individual widths are scaled so that their height is the same

I do this styling frequently with elements of different dimensions, so I would prefer that styling be general and not specific to two specific images’ dimensions.

I have attached an example of what I intend it to look like. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUOh.jpg)

How can I achieve this using just HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You could use object-fit:cover like in following example,
or use the images as background-images. I don't have any other idea how to solve the issue you described. Maybe there are some better answers to this.

```css
.container {
background-color:#dadada;
width:100%;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:center;
}

.image-container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 max-width:600px;
 max-height:250px;
 display:flex;
 padding:3rem 0;
}

img {
 width:50%;
 height:auto;
 object-fit:cover;
 object-position: 50% 50%; /* Default Value but with this you could change the position */
}

/* Second Example with background-image */

.image {
 width:50%;
 height:250px;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:center center;
}

.image span {
background-color:white;
padding:0.5rem;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


  <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200" width="500" height="200"/>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/500" width="100" height="500"/>
  </div>
  
   <div class="image-container">
     <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/500/200')"><span>Image Size: 500 x 200 px</span></div>
     <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/100/500')"><span>Image Size: 100 x 500 px</span></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @chris-schober! Unfortunately its crucial to maintain the original dimensions of the images, so object-fit:cover and anything with background images won't suffice :(